# Authentication settings in IIS 7.5 and ASP.Net, what is difference?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, web-config

I just start to learn web programming using IIS 7.5 in windows 2008 R2, and ASP.Net 4.

I notice that both IIS and ASP.Net can define Authentication rules. In IIS, there is a form authentication setting where I can redirect user to specified page for authentication, like below:

[image]

And then, in ASP web.config file, I find similar settings:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

When I finish both settings, I assume any page request will be redirect to the login.aspx page. But it didn't. So I am confused. How do the 2 sets of configs work together? And why page request is not redirected?

Thanks

**Update**

Finally I get it working and I think I understand it now. My website structure is like below:

[image]

It is about modifying Autherization rules. Deny all unauthorized users for root:

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

CSS files should be allowed for all users, so I have Styles\web.config:

```
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

and only allow unauthorized users to access register.aspx, so I have Account\web.config:

```
  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another component you need to configure: authorization. If you don't, unauthorized users have access to all pages and will not be redirected to the login page. For example:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

This specifies that all unauthenticated users are denied access to pages in your application. The `authorization` element is part of the `system.web` configuration section.

Comment: Hi, i added this but it gives me same error rather than redirection. Seems redirection is not automatic?

Comment: Glad you worked it out. If this helped you answer your question, could you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1):

When you set something in IIS with authentication ( in your case form authentication). It also change your mapped project webconfig file with the same settings. That's why you see same information in both modules.

Comment: you are right. And when I enable all 3 methods in IIS, web.config only uses 'Forms'. Does that mean Form method takes priority?

Comment: Try 
<system.web>
  <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
 <location path="login.aspx">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
Let user to connect to mentioned page in webconfig.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

This section sets the authentication policies of the application. Possible modes are "Windows", "Forms", "Passport" and "None". Because you have one of these, webconfig contains only one.